# Slick doesnt input data in h2 database

Tags: database, scala, playframework-2.0, h2, slick-3.0

Im stuck with this problem a couple days now. I have the right connection and the right queries but when i run the application nothing changes in my database, could it be that its running my html webpages on localhost:9000 instead of executing the Slick queries?
im using IntelliJ IDEA 1.15 and the Typesafe Activator

Build:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
jdbc,
cache,
ws,
specs2 % Test,
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.1.0-RC2",
"org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.7.10",
"org.slf4j" % "jcl-over-slf4j"  % "1.7.10",
"com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.187",
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test"
).map(_.force())
// login embed:       jdbc:h2:~/test1
// login servermode:  jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test1
libraryDependencies += evolutions
```

Application.conf:

```
h2mem1 = {
url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test1"
driver = org.h2.Driver
connectionPool = disabled
keepAliveConnection = true
}

db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:test1;MODE=MYSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
db.default.username=sa
db.default.password=""
```

BarisDatabase:

```
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Await}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import slick.backend.DatabasePublisher
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._

// The main application
object BarisDatabase extends App {
val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:h2:mem:test1;MODE=MYSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1", driver="org.h2.Driver")
try {

// The query interface for the Suppliers table
val suppliers: TableQuery[Suppliers] = TableQuery[Suppliers]

// the query interface for the Coffees table
val coffees: TableQuery[Coffees] = TableQuery[Coffees]

val setupAction: DBIO[Unit] = DBIO.seq(
  // Create the schema by combining the DDLs for the Suppliers and Coffees
  // tables using the query interfaces
  (suppliers.schema ++ coffees.schema).create,

  // Insert some suppliers
  suppliers += (101, "Acme, Inc.", "99 Market Street", "Groundsville", "CA", "95199"),
  suppliers += ( 49, "Superior Coffee", "1 Party Place", "Mendocino", "CA", "95460"),
  suppliers += (150, "The High Ground", "100 Coffee Lane", "Meadows", "CA", "93966")
)

val setupFuture: Future[Unit] = db.run(setupAction)
val f = setupFuture.flatMap { _ =>

  // Insert some coffees (using JDBC's batch insert feature)
  val insertAction: DBIO[Option[Int]] = coffees ++= Seq (
    ("Colombian",         101, 7.99, 0, 0),
    ("French_Roast",       49, 8.99, 0, 0),
    ("Espresso",          150, 9.99, 0, 0),
    ("Colombian_Decaf",   101, 8.99, 0, 0),
    ("French_Roast_Decaf", 49, 9.99, 0, 0)
  )

  val insertAndPrintAction: DBIO[Unit] = insertAction.map { coffeesInsertResult =>
    // Print the number of rows inserted
    coffeesInsertResult foreach { numRows =>
      println(s"Inserted $numRows rows into the Coffees table")
    }
  }

  val allSuppliersAction: DBIO[Seq[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)]] =
    suppliers.result

  val combinedAction: DBIO[Seq[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)]] =
    insertAndPrintAction >> allSuppliersAction

  val combinedFuture: Future[Seq[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)]] =
    db.run(combinedAction)

  combinedFuture.map { allSuppliers =>
    allSuppliers.foreach(println)
  }
  }
  } finally db.close
  }
```

Tables.scala:

```
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._
import slick.lifted.{ProvenShape, ForeignKeyQuery}

// A Suppliers table with 6 columns: id, name, street, city, state, zip class Suppliers(tag: Tag)
extends Table[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)](tag, "SUPPLIERS") {

// This is the primary key column:
def id: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("SUP_ID", O.PrimaryKey)
def name: Rep[String] = column[String]("SUP_NAME")
def street: Rep[String] = column[String]("STREET")
def city: Rep[String] = column[String]("CITY")
def state: Rep[String] = column[String]("STATE")
def zip: Rep[String] = column[String]("ZIP")

// Every table needs a * projection with the same type as the table's type parameter
def * : ProvenShape[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)] =
(id, name, street, city, state, zip)
}

// A Coffees table with 5 columns: name, supplier id, price, sales, total
class Coffees(tag: Tag)
extends Table[(String, Int, Double, Int, Int)](tag, "COFFEES") {

def name: Rep[String] = column[String]("COF_NAME", O.PrimaryKey)
def supID: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("SUP_ID")
def price: Rep[Double] = column[Double]("PRICE")
def sales: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("SALES")
def total: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("TOTAL")

def * : ProvenShape[(String, Int, Double, Int, Int)] = (name, supID, price, sales, total)

// A reified foreign key relation that can be navigated to create a join
def supplier: ForeignKeyQuery[Suppliers, (Int, String, String, String, String, String)] =
foreignKey("SUP_FK", supID, TableQuery[Suppliers])(_.id)
}
```

i got most of these codes from the tutorial Hello-Slick-3.1 in the Typesafe Activator.
[Filestructure in IntelliJ IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjqLY.png)

I hope that this is enough information

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:h2:mem:test1;MODE=MYSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1", driver="org.h2.Driver")
```

to

```
val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")
```

Comment: H2 is a memory database. This mean that all data that you write goes to memory imitation of real database. Do you try to use MySQL database or you fail during writing your data to memory database?

Comment: i fail at writing data in my h2 database, plus i changed the URL of my database, now it places the tables in my home directory

jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/c:/users/Creativename/test1

Comment: Once again you write to memory, not to hard drive or real database. And all that your program does it creates couple of entities and print them to the console. If you do not see them in your console delete all db.default lines from app.conf and keep `Database.forConfig("h2mem1")` as your db configuration.